# I have committed changes to git locally and now want to work off this on another computer without checking in to master

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have a remote git repo (on github) and a working copy on my local workstation. Due to travel, I now want to continue this work on another computer. I have committed all my changes locally. How do I grab this latest code from another git client without pushing to master on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- Push to a different branch. For example, the following command will push your local branch `master` to a remote branch called `newbranch`.

  ```
  git push origin master:newbranch
  ```

  Then, you can fetch on another computer and work on that branch from there.
- Add one of your repositories as a remote to the other. If you have a network filesystem the two computers share, this is easy. Otherwise, [it's more complicated](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server).
- Move the repository. You can copy-paste the entire repository to your new computer. Git stores everything it needs in the `.git` directory in your working copy. Grab the whole thing and you can work on a different machine.